# Debug Lua in a Java project using LuaJava

Tags: java, android, debugging, lua

My project has LuaJava as the script interpreter, for usage in both desktop and android via AndroLua. I want to be able to debug it, but I'm unable to arrange it.

I have tried with an Eclipse plugin, Koneki, which is poorly documented and only seems able to debug Lua-only projects. I tried doing [as the tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/Developer_Area/User_Guides/User_Guide_0.9#Attach_session) but it doesn't accept my project as valid for not having lua capabilities. I tried then using a secondary project linking my Lua files, launching the debugger and then my project, but the process does not attach. I tried using the methods provided by the tutorial but they throw an "non-existing Lua method" error.

I have also tried Decoda, but despite being able of launching the executable no symbol pdb files exist so the breakpoints are not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting ZeroBraneStudio's creator, it is now posible to debug AndroLua and LuaJava on his IDE.

Instructions [here](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging.html). This functionality is available from v0.38 onwards.

Comment: this functionality is now included in ZeroBrane Studio v0.38 available from the [project website](http://studio.zerobrane.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I use koneki and it works a treat for lua embedded in c/c++/objective c - it should work for luajava but haven't tried it. Whats the message you get in Koneki, there are a few things you need to setup. In particular lua socket in your path, and the debugger.lua in your LUA_PATH.

These lines in your first lua file loaded

```
require "socket"
local initconnection = require("debugger")
initconnection("127.0.0.1", 10000, "luaidekey")
```

if you still have probs leave a comment

Comment: stdin:1: module 'debugger' not found:
        no field package.preload['debugger']
        no file './debugger.lua'
        no file 'C:\Lua\ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/debugger/debugger.lua'
        no file 'C:\Lua\ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/debugger.lua'
        no file 'C:/Lua/5.1/'
        no file 'C:\Lua\ZeroBraneStudio/bin/debugger.dll'
        no file 'C:\Lua\ZeroBraneStudio/bin/clibs/debugger.dll'
        no file 'C:/Lua/5.1/'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?

Comment: LUA_PATH: ./?.lua;%ZBS%/lualibs/?/?.lua;%ZBS%/lualibs/?.lua;C:/Lua/5.1/

LUA_CPATH: %ZBS%/bin/?.dll;%ZBS%/bin/clibs/?.dll;C:/Lua/5.1/

Comment: In here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/Developer_Area/User_Guides/User_Guide_0.9#Attach_session it shows a link 'Lua Debugger Client' displayed in eclipse, click on that and LDT will copy the debugger.lua files to wherever you select

Comment: I already did it, it doesn't work. I could talk to the developer of a Lua IDE and he said LuaJava feeds the code as a string, not as a file, so the debugger doesn't know to which file they come from.

Comment: By doesn't work do you mean eclipse doesn't generate the files?

Comment: I selected the files, and the files were copied, and the debugger was started, the lines were executed but the debugger did not attach to the process. I have been able to attach the process to a debugger in other environments, but the debugger cannot work because the code is not fed as files but as strings so it doesn't know where to look.

Comment: not arguing just curious. So if a file is "required" then luajava intercepts that somehow or other does it?

Comment: You have the java files and a native library. The native library includes the interpreter, so it doesn't go through the one you have installed in your PC or phone. Then it feeds the instructions to the interpreter as strings, after reading them from files.

Your desktop's debugger doesn't know how or where to attach to the interpreter, so we change to remote. We load a script for remote debugging and it attaches, but it doesn't have a way of knowing where the files come from.

Comment: Oh Ok, I don't know if the debug interface will work without a file. I use it for developing on the IPad using an emulator and it works because the directory containing the lua files is mapped to the emulator. So if you could map the files somehow or other then you'd be fine, but I suspect you've already tried this - good luck :-)